# marshall and unmarshall partially-defined yaml structure with custom yaml tags intact

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

I am trying to marshal and unmarshal an [authentik blueprint](https://goauthentik.io/developer-docs/blueprints/) into a custom resource for a Kubernetes operator (operator SDK / controller runtime).
There are a few constraints:

1. Authentik blueprints can vary substantially in certain areas like `.entries.attrs` we do not want to define a set schema under this key as it is too varied to be maintainable.
2. Authentik blueprints use custom yaml tags like `!KeyOf` and `!Find` which should be maintained as is without changing the subsequent arguments like `!Find [authentik_flows.flow, [slug, default-password-change]]` should stay as is after unmarshall + marshall.

Here is an example authentik blueprint:

```
version: 1
metadata:
  name: Default - Authentication flow
entries:
- attrs:
    backends:
    - authentik.core.auth.InbuiltBackend
    - authentik.sources.ldap.auth.LDAPBackend
    - authentik.core.auth.TokenBackend
    configure_flow: !Find [authentik_flows.flow, [slug, default-password-change]]
  identifiers:
    name: default-authentication-password
  id: default-authentication-password
  model: authentik_stages_password.passwordstage
- attrs:
    user_fields:
    - email
    - username
  identifiers:
    name: default-authentication-identification
  id: default-authentication-identification
  model: authentik_stages_identification.identificationstage
- identifiers:
    name: default-authentication-login
  id: default-authentication-login
  model: authentik_stages_user_login.userloginstage
- identifiers:
    order: 10
    stage: !KeyOf default-authentication-identification
    target: !KeyOf flow
  model: authentik_flows.flowstagebinding
```

To solve issue 1. I tried defining a schema that used `json.RawMessage` as the type of highly uncertain keys like `.entries.attrs`. However I found that `json.RawMessage` would strip and unpack the custom yaml tags from constraint 2. .

I have also been experimenting with `yaml.Node` (from go-yaml v3 but does not have `DeepCopyInto` type function), `[]byte`, `interface{}` and `map[string]interface{}`.

Here is my current schema that succeeds at solving issue 1. but is disastrous for issue 2. (the full code is available [here](https://gitlab.com/GeorgeRaven/authentik-manager/-/blob/10391326acd05efddf0d94bede6c979b390d5b95/operator/api/v1alpha1/akblueprint_types.go) if more detail is needed):

```
import (
"encoding/json"

metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

...

// BP is a whole blueprint struct containing the full structure of an authentik blueprint
// https://goauthentik.io/developer-docs/blueprints/v1/structure#structure
type BP struct {
//+kubebuilder:default=1

// Version is the version of this blueprint
Version int `json:"version"`

// Metadata block specifying labels and names of the blueprint
Metadata BPMeta `json:"metadata"`

// +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields
// +kubebuilder:validation:Schemaless

// Context (optional) authentik default context (whatever that means)
Context json.RawMessage `json:"context,omitempty"`

// +kubebuilder:validation:MinItems=1

// Entries lists models we want to use via this blueprint
Entries []BPModel `json:"entries"`
}

// BPMeta is the metadata of an authentik blueprint as authentik likes
type BPMeta struct {

// +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields
// +kubebuilder:validation:Schemaless

// Labels (optional) key-value store for special labels
// https://goauthentik.io/developer-docs/blueprints/v1/structure#special-labels
Labels json.RawMessage `json:"labels,omitempty"`

// Name of the authentik blueprint for authentik to register
Name string `json:"name"`
}

// BPModel is a rough outline of the structure of models authentik likes in its blueprints
type BPModel struct {

// Model "app.model" notation of which model from authentik to call
Model string `json:"model"`

//+kubebuilder:validation:Enum="present";"create";"absent"
//+kubebuilder:default:=present

// State (optional) desired state of this model when loaded from "present", "create", "absent"
// present: (default) keeps the object in sync with its definition in this blueprint
// create: only creates the initial object with its values here
// absent: deletes the object
State string `json:"state,omitempty"`

// Conditions (optional) a list of conditions which if all match the model will be activated. If not the model will be inactive
Conditions []string `json:"conditions,omitempty"`

// +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields
// +kubebuilder:validation:Schemaless

// Identifiers key-value identifiers to allow filtering of this stage, and identifying it
Identifiers json.RawMessage `json:"identifiers"`

// Id (optional) is similar to identifiers except is optional and is just an ID to reference this model using !KeyOf syntax in authentik
Id string `json:"id,omitempty"`

// +kubebuilder:pruning:PreserveUnknownFields
// +kubebuilder:validation:Schemaless

// Attrs is a map of settings / options / overrides of the defaults of this model
Attrs json.RawMessage `json:"attrs,omitempty"`
}
```

I have been tearing my hair out trying to find a good solution, any help would be much appreciated.